# add vertical and horizontal alignment to Jetpack compose custom layouts

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I created a custom grid layout for a list of items. The problem I am facing is that when I apply an resizing animation 100->150 or 150-100. The item looks like it is animating from and to the top start. What I am trying to achieve is it to animate from the center

```
        val spacing = if(placeables.isNotEmpty()) {
            (constraints.maxWidth - placeables.first().width * 4)/5
        } else {
            0
        }

        placeables.forEach { placeable ->
            if(currentGroupWidth + placeable.width <= constraints.maxWidth){
                currentGroup.add(placeable)
                currentGroupWidth += placeable.width
            }
            else{
                groupedPlaceable.add(currentGroup)
                currentGroup = mutableListOf(placeable)
                currentGroupWidth = placeable.width
            }
        }

        if(currentGroup.isNotEmpty()){
            groupedPlaceable.add(currentGroup)
        }

        layout(width = constraints.maxWidth, height = constraints.maxHeight) {
            var yPosition = 0
            groupedPlaceable.forEach { row ->
                var xPosition = spacing
                row.forEach { placeable ->
                    placeable.place(
                        x = xPosition,
                        y = yPosition,
                    )
                    xPosition += placeable.width + spacing
                }
                yPosition += row.maxOfOrNull { it.height + spacing} ?: 0
            }
        }
```